# Does Postscript have a concept of a table?

Tags: pdf, postscript

What I'm trying to achieve is to determine if the Postscript that I'm parsing contains any element that resides in a table (box).

Im asking whether if it had a built-in way to lay out tabular data on the page. My guess is that postscript doesnt have a concept of a table, cos I couldnt find it anywhere in the spec.

The problem that i need to solve is, I need to find a way to know if certain postscript lies inside a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to draw something and test if any part of draws within some specified box.   You can create a path for the thing to be tested (just don't stroke or fill it), and create another path for the box (e.g. a table cell).  Leave these two paths on the stack, and use one of the operators inufill, inustroke, etc.

If you happen to have the Postscript Language Reference 3rd edition, the goodies are listed under "Insideness-Testing Operators" on p. 520, with details in the alphabetical section following that.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.   it's a low level language for describing where to put ink on a page, no concepts of organizing it besides lines, arcs and beziers connecting x,y points put on the stack.

That said - i have written postscript by hand, and it would be smart to create variables, or  arrays of x and of y values to use for aligning points.  The arrays would be especially useful inside a for loop which renders the contents and draws border lines. Beware of fencepost bugs!

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to code the table yourself.

I did this once many years ago. After being fed up with TeX, I wrote an interpreter in PostScript that did similar things. Never found much use for it though.